# Get selected index list title blackberry java

Tags: java, blackberry

Currently when i click on any list item, it get index of of first clicked list item index, means if i click on videos, it save video click index even when i click on images it shows video data. i want when i click on any item it shows only that selected index data and that is possible i get selected item list title dynamically ??

```
Vector v = new Vector();
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        final String listTitle = _folderList[i]._fileName;
        v.addElement(new ListRander(closedIcon, listTitle, playIcon));
        // CustomListField With Event
        myListView = new CustomListField(v) {
            public boolean trackwheelClick(int status, int time) {
                // which row is selected?
                int index = getSelectedIndex();
                if (index == 0) {
                    String ImageIndex = "Images";
                    UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new ImagesList(ImageIndex, _ftp));
                }
                if (index == 1) {
                    String MusicIndex = "Music";
                    UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new MusicList(MusicIndex, _ftp));
                }
                if (index == 2) {
                    String VideoIndex = "Video";
                    UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new VideosList(VideoIndex, _ftp));
                }
                return true;
            }
        };
    }// For Loop End
    add(myListView);
```

Comment: Sorry I appreciate that English is possibly not your first language, but the question makes no sense to me.  Perhaps you could describe in steps what your program currently does and what you want it to do.

Comment: @PeterStrange, I *believe* he's saying that no matter how he scrolls, his code only ever gets into the same `if` branch (e.g. where `index == 2`), no matter which list row he's on.  I think Mister Smith nailed it, that not allowing the base class `trackwheelClick()` method to ever run prevents `getSelectedIndex()` from being able to properly track the selected row.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to return `super.trackwheelClick()` instead.

Returning true means that the event is consumed. As you dont call the parent class handler, your list can't know it has been clicked, and it returns the last selected item (which is the first element by default).

As a final tip: don't use `trackwheelClick`, because it wont work in touchscreen enabled devices. Use `navigationClick` or `FieldChangeListener` instead.