# Select title of selected list item on new screen - Custom list field Blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I want to get selected list row title on new screen, but i get only last list row title no matter which list row is clicked.

Here is a sample code:

```
Bitmap listThumb = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("icon.png");// Dummy Icon
    listTitle = "Headline"; // Dummy value
    Bitmap navBar = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("icon.png");// Dummy Icon
    Vector v = new Vector();
    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        listTitle = listTitle + i;
        v.addElement(new ListRander(listThumb, listTitle, navBar));
        myListView = new CustomListField(v) {
            public boolean trackwheelClick(int status, int time) {
                int index = getSelectedIndex();
                // get selected index title ...
                UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(
                        new InnerPage(listTitle));
                return true;
            }
        };
    }
    add(myListView);
```

And possible to get title by using FieldChangeListener & how ??

Answer (score 0):

This code is virtually identical to this question:

[Get selected index list title blackberry java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19914288/get-selected-index-list-title-blackberry-java)

But perhaps the problem is a bit different.

Firstly there appears to be a logic error here.  This looks wrong:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    listTitle = listTitle + i;
    v.addElement(new ListRander(listThumb, listTitle, navBar));
    myListView = new CustomListField(v) {
        public boolean trackwheelClick(int status, int time) {
            int index = getSelectedIndex();
            // get selected index title ...
            UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(
                    new InnerPage(listTitle));
            return true;
        }
    };
```

}

Shouldn't it be:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    listTitle = listTitle + i;
    v.addElement(new ListRander(listThumb, listTitle, navBar));
}
myListView = new CustomListField(v) {
    public boolean trackwheelClick(int status, int time) {
        int index = getSelectedIndex();
        // get selected index title ...
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(
                new InnerPage(listTitle));
        return true;
    }
};
```

Given this, replace trackwheelClick() with navigationClick() as suggested in the referenced Thread.

Debug the index returned by this line:

```
int index = getSelectedIndex();
```

If this is always the last value, then the problem is in getSelectedIndex() method of your CustomListField, which of course we don't have....

If it is the index value you expect it to be, then you can reference the associated element in your Vector v.

Comment: i get expected value from index means it give selected row index value but how i can refer the associated element in Vector v?? --  @Peter Strange.

Comment: @KabirSomro - v.elementAt(index) - I recommend reviewing the JavaDocs.

Comment: i have try to implement by using  http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/vector_elementat.htm, but not get selected row listTitle value on next screen.

Comment: I suggest you use the actual BB JavaDocs - which for OS 7.1 you find here: http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/.  If you are choosing the correct element from your Vector, and you put that element in the Vector, then it seems that you should know how to interpret this, and so how to determine what you want to use as a title. It seems you put instances of class ListRander in the Vector v, so cast the element as a ListRander Object and hopefully there is  a getTitle() or similar method.  Standard java really.